# Sass compile adds unnecessary stuff

Tags: sass

I am using phpstorm and compiling my sass through filewatcher. After compiling in my css there is @charset "UTF-8" at the beginning when there shouldn't be. Also it coverts my single quotation marks to double quotation marks. How can I disable that?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `@charset` directly or have replaced by a BOM (byte order mark) if you specify your output style as [`compressed`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#compressed), but you cannot disable it outright. From the [Encodings section](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#encodings) of the reference documentation:

> Sass will always encode its output as UTF-8. It will include a @charset declaration if and only if the output file contains non-ASCII characters. In compressed mode, a UTF-8 byte order mark is used in place of a @charset declaration.

The quotes you use to author your strings in Sass should carry forward to your compiled CSS, so you'll have to include an example of the code you're using that demonstrates the behaviour you're describing. If you're doing any kind of interpolation or are performing operations on your strings, then that may explain why they're output in double quotes.